# Python design mistakes

Tags: python

A while ago, when I was learning Javascript, I studied [Javascript: the good parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742), and I particularly enjoyed the chapters on the bad and the ugly parts. Of course, I did not agree with everything, as summing up the design defects of a programming language is to a certain extent subjective - although, for instance, I guess everyone would agree that the keyword `with` was a mistake in Javascript. Nevertheless, I find it useful to read such reviews: even if one does not agree, there is a lot to learn.

Is there a blog entry or some book describing design mistakes for Python? For instance I guess some people would count the lack of tail call optimization a mistake; there may be other issues (or non-issues) which are worth learning about.

Comment: Tail call optimization is not a language design issue.

Comment: Yes, it is the LACK of that which is an issue, at least according to some. It is not only a problem of optimization actually: it prevents from using a recursive style of coding, as you quickly go over the maximum recursion limit. If you google python tail call optimization you will find plenty of discussions about that, including a couple of blog posts by Guido.

Comment: Yes, but optimizing tail calls or not doing so is not a language design issue, it's an implementation detail. It's perfectly possible to optimize tail calls without changing anything about the language. A different implementation might (PyPy perhaps?), as well as a future version of CPython.

Comment: @delnan: Actually it is not an implementation detail, read [Guido's post](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html) about it.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: The second point (that including the optimization leads to code relying on it) is true. But this is still nothing that is set in stone in the language! (Also, one could argue if this isn't true for most optimizations and if this is an issue - after all, not even Haskell programmers use explicit recursion very often, the use `fold`, `map` and friends for nearly everything).

Comment: @Whoever voted to close: please, can you explain why? I would think this is a legitimate question: I'm looking for resources discussing Python shortages. Please, note that I'm NOT inviting to discuss them here (would that be allowed?).

Comment: @Andrea: Optimization is a compiler/run-time issue.  Not a language issue.

Comment: Optimization has nothing to do with language design. Yes, I understand that. Still, not having optimization does not allow for some coding style, and Guido explicitly stated that this is the main reason why CPython does not do optimization. So it is a compiler issue motivated by design considerations.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I'd argue that while the BDFL makes a good case that recursion isn't central to Python, optimization is still possible.  The 1000-level stack limit is a run-time feature not a language feature.  So I think that Python--the language--won't change in syntax or semantics if TRE is added to the run-time.  Depending on this leads to inefficiencies and problems, true, but it's more of a run-time optimization than a proper language feature like the `return` statement being optional.

Comment: @Andrea: Not design.  Debugging.  The lack of Python optimization is for two reasons.  1) debugging is really hard with optimization, and 2) it's a dynamic language in which code can be created on-the-fly.  Optimization is more complex when you have monkey-patching at run-time.  Neither has an impact on the language.  Only the run-time.

Comment: @Andrea: FWIW, I agree that not implementing TCO *is* a design feature of Python since it’s *explicitly* omitted to discourage people from relying on it, thus forcing (or rather, prohibiting) a certain style of programming. That sounds very much designed to me.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Designed, yes.  But one could crack open pypy, implement it, and go home happy and successful with no language changes.  Unit tests all pass.  It's a carefully thought-out position, agreed.  But I think it's more an implementation decision, than a language design decision.

Comment: @S.Lott: but it reflects *fundamentally* of how the language can be used, and *that* is a language design issue. Using recursion except in very special circumstances is essentially a no-go in Python that is enforced (and make no mistake; it *would* otherwise be broken) by pypy’s not implementing TCO.

Comment: If a language spec doesn't specify that it must have tail call optimization, then you can't rely on it being there. If you can't rely on it being there, then you can't really write code that uses it, since it will blow up on an implementation without it. Knowing you can't use tail call optimization means you need to write your code differently. It's not just a matter of "write the cleanest code and let the implementation make it work faster"

Comment: Surprised no one has brought up the ugly `__` syntax, especially `__init__`. It's a pretty common function to use, yet the use of the underscore makes it appear like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You asked for a link or other source, but there really isn't one. The information is spread over many different places. What really constitutes a design mistake, and do you count just syntactic and semantic issues in the language definition, or do you include pragmatic things like platform and standard library issues and specific implementation issues? You could say that Python's dynamism is a design mistake from a performance perspective, because it makes it hard to make a straightforward efficient implementation, and it makes it hard (I didn't say completely impossible) to make an IDE with code completion, refactoring, and other nice things. At the same time, you could argue for the pros of dynamic languages.

Maybe one approach to start thinking about this is to look at [the language changes from Python 2.x to 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/index.html). Some people would of course argue that `print` being a function is inconvenient, while others think it's an improvement. Overall, there are not that many changes, and most of them are quite small and subtle. For example, `map()` and `filter()` return iterators instead of lists, `range()` behaves like `xrange()` used to, and `dict` methods like `dict.keys()` return views instead of lists. Then there are some changes related to integers, and one of the big changes is binary/string data handling. It's now *text* and *data*, and text is always Unicode. There are several syntactic changes, but they are more about consistency than revamping the whole language.

From this perspective, it appears that Python has been pretty well designed on the language (syntax and sematics) level since at least 2.x. You can always argue about indentation-based block syntax, but we all know that doesn't lead anywhere... ;-)

Another approach is to look at what alternative Python implementations are trying to address. Most of them address performance in some way, some address platform issues, and some add or make changes to the language itself to more efficiently solve certain kinds of tasks. [Unladen swallow](https://code.google.com/archive/p/unladen-swallow/) wants to make Python significantly faster by optimizing the runtime byte-compilation and execution stages. [Stackless](https://github.com/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki) adds functionality for efficient, heavily threaded applications by adding constructs like microthreads and tasklets, channels to allow bidirectional tasklet communication, scheduling to run tasklets cooperatively or preemptively, and serialisation to suspend and resume tasklet execution. [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) allows using Python on the Java platform and [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/) on the .Net platform. [Cython](https://cython.org/) is a Python dialect which allows calling C functions and declaring C types, allowing the compiler to generate efficient C code from Cython code. [Shed Skin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/shedskin/) brings implicit static typing into Python and generates C++ for standalone programs or extension modules. [PyPy](http://codespeak.net/pypy/) implements Python in a subset of Python, and changes some implementation details like adding garbage collection instead of reference counting. The purpose is to allow Python language and implementation development to become more efficient due to the higher-level language. [Py V8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/) bridges Python and JavaScript through the V8 JavaScript engine – you could say it's solving a platform issue. [Psyco](http://psyco.sourceforge.net/) is a special kind of JIT that dynamically generates special versions of the running code for the data that is currently being handled, which can give speedups for your Python code without having to write optimised C modules.

Of these, something can be said about the current state of Python by looking at [PEP-3146](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3146/) which outlines how Unladen Swallow would be merged into CPython. This PEP is accepted and is thus the Python developers' judgement of what is the most feasible direction to take at the moment. Note it addresses performance, not the language per se.

So really I would say that Python's main design *problems* are in the performance domain – but these are basically the same challenges that any dynamic language has to face, and the Python family of languages and implementations are trying to address the issues. As for outright design *mistakes* like the ones listed in [Javascript: the good parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742), I think the meaning of "mistake" needs to be more explicitly defined, but you may want to check out the following for thoughts and opinions:

- [FLOSS Weekly 11: Guido van Rossum](https://twit.tv/shows/floss-weekly/episodes/11) (podcast August 4th, 2006)
- [The History of Python blog](https://python-history.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 33):

> Is there a blog entry or some book describing design mistakes for Python?

Yes.

It's called the Py3K list of backwards-incompatible changes.

Start here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Read all the Python 3.x release notes for additional details on the mistakes in Python 2.

Comment: +1 for a source that has zero reason to bash Python but lists many things that can relaltively unambigiously be considered mistakes.

Comment: @delnan: "relaltively unambigiously"?  It's totally unambiguous.  They're changing them.  Therefore, they must have been absolute, total mistakes.

Comment: Uh-oh. I consider it one of Python’s biggest fortes that it broke backwards compatibility. I wish more languages had the balls to do this. Imagine we’d still have to use VHS “because DVDs break backwards compatibility.”

Comment: It's possible (although moot anyway) that one disagrees with these decisions. The people who designed Python 3 consider these things mistakes - they are wise Python programmers, but that doesn't make whatever they choose not to keep a misfeature.

Comment: Damn. I completely misunderstood your point, Steven. I’ll let my previous comment stand because I still think breaking backwards compatibility is a commendable trait of Python. But here’s your upvote. ;-)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - I wish I could arm you and send you back in time to when C99 was being standardised.

Comment: So py3k solves all the problems I guess there is no need for a Python4 ;)

Comment: @Ismail: Well, they might choose to call it Python 4 instead of Python 3.10. But it is indeed very unlikely that another backwards incompatible release like Python 3 will ever come again.

Comment: @Lennart thats because people even didn't adopt Python3, and now the idea is to get incremental updates instead of a language overhaul like Python3 did. There will be mistakes and we'll suck with it.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: "people even didn't adopt Python3"?  From the SO questions, people seem to be adopting it pretty quickly.  What claim are you making?

Comment: @Ismail: "thats because people even didn't adopt Python3" why are you using the past tense there? Adoption is ongoing. "and now the idea is to get incremental updates instead of a language overhaul like Python3 did" - Not at all. There will be no *need* for language overhauls.

Comment: @S.Lott please read Guido's mail on his reasoning to stop bumping Python version and instead stabilize Python3 (for at least 2-3 years) and get it adopted. Here what I see on SO is that people still didn't even get used to the `bytes` vs `str` change.

Comment: @Ismail: The moratorium is to let other implementations catch up. It has nothing to do with getting Python 3 adopted, nor anything to do with overhauls vs incremental updates.

Comment: The adoption will be slow, but that's understandable. The vast majority of Python packages I use still don't work with Python3, and my Linux distro is still standardized on Python2.6, but things will change. Backwards incompatible releases are sometimes necessary, but can be quite painful. PHP did this some years ago, and got a lot of flak for it, but the language is better off for it.

Answer (score 23):

My biggest peeve with Python - and one which was not really addressed in the move to 3.x - is the lack of proper naming conventions in the standard library.

Why, for example, does the `datetime` module contain a class itself called `datetime`? (To say nothing of why we have separate `datetime` and `time` modules, but also a `datetime.time` class!) Why is `datetime.datetime` in lower case, but `decimal.Decimal` is upper case? And please, tell me why we have that terrible mess under the `xml` namespace: `xml.sax`, but `xml.etree.ElementTree` - what is going on there?

Comment: I see your point, but this has not much to do with the language design.

Comment: The standard library has naming mistakes, and I would like PEP8 being followed consistently too (e.g. class, including `datetime`, should be CamelCase). But to be fair, Python 3 did fix *some* of these issues (e.g. tkinter module is no longer capitalized, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately libraries / APIs tend to be like that. Conventions reflect personal preferences and with libraries refactoring is typically not an option due to existing code bases.  Personally, I prefer the Smalltalk naming conventions and that's how I write my Python apps. PEP8 makes it easier for people to grok libraries, but as you say, more could have been done in this area with code reviews.  Maybe in Python4!

Comment: Another PEP 8 violation is in method and function names: builtins and a large part of the standard library don't separate words with underscores. Examples: `isinstance`, `startswith`, `issubset`, `deleteacl`, `endheaders`...

Answer (score 5):

Try these links:

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonLanguage

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PythonProblems

Comment: But while reading (this or any other text on this topic) that (1) a considerable part of the complaints raised is not related to language design, (2) many of the others are instead considered good or the lesser evil by most who care to think about the language design and the possible alternative (see e.g. Alex Martelli's answers ) and (3) most of the remaining ones are tradeoffs that aren't decided easily, and are fine either way so it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: IMO, the "whitespace issue" is a strength, not a weakness. It's probably my favorite feature of the language, although I admit as an ex-C++ programmer I felt uneasy about it at first. I've since saved countless hours *not* having to write redundant }/fi/end/endif statements.

Comment: The whitespace issue is purely a personal preference thing, really. I hate it, as do a lot of others... and just as many love it. It has both benefits and drawbacks.

Answer (score 5):

Things that frequently surprise inexperienced developers are candidate mistakes.  Here is one, default arguments:

http://www.deadlybloodyserious.com/2008/05/default-argument-blunders/

Answer (score 4):

A personal *language* peeve of mine is name binding for lambdas / local functions:

```
fns = []
for i in range(10):
    fns.append(lambda: i)

for fn in fns:
    print(fn()) # !!! always 9 - not what I'd naively expect
```

IMO, I'd much prefer looking up the names referenced in a lambda at declaration time. I understand the reasons for why it works the way it does, but still...

You currently have to work around it by binding `i` into a new name whos value doesn't change, using a function closure.

Comment: There's also the `lambda i=i: i` trick.

Comment: You're right, I didn't mention that workaround. Quite ugly, though, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, most of the time you want lexical scopes to capture values, not variables. But capturing variables is more powerful...

Comment: This problem is also quite common in JavaScript; the way to avoid it when designing a language is to provide a new lexical scope for loops (and `if` blocks and so on) as well as for function calls, which ironically is what languages *without* closures such as C generally do. Unfortunately, the workaround used in JS, methods like `Array::forEach` that make each iteration a function call and therefore give them their own lexical scopes, is not an option in Python since its lambdas are so weak.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a minor problem with the language, rather than a fundamental mistake, but: **Property overriding.** If you override a property (using getters and setters), there is no easy way of getting the parent class' property.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's strange but I guess that's what you get for having mutable variables.

I think the reason is that the "i" refers to a box which has a mutable value and the "for" loop will change that value over time, so reading the box value later gets you the only value there is left.
I don't know how one would fix that short of making it a functional programming language without mutable variables (at least without unchecked mutable variables).

The workaround I use is creating a new variable with a default value (default values being evaluated at DEFINITION time in Python, which is annoying at other times) which causes copying of the value to the new box:

```
fns = []
for i in range(10):
    fns.append(lambda j=i: j)

for fn in fns:
    print(fn()) # works
```

Comment: It seems like this was meant to be a comment on Tom Whittock's answer.

Comment: Danny, it is the *name* that mutates, not the "value" (I think you mean object.) The issue is that the name is looked up, as in PEP 227, rather than being bound into the method at declaration time.

Comment: Max: Yea... though it doesn't seem I can move it there :-(

@Tom: It is? I thought the problem was that the for loop variable was being actually mutated and the name i was still referring to the same box (whose contents are being changed over time). If it were just a name problem, shouldn't lambda j=i not fix it? I've read PEP 227 now and don't see what you mean yet...

Comment: Danny, there is a globally unique object representing each integer, which does not mutate. You can verify this with `1 is (4-3)`, for example. So the object does not mutate, but the name `i` is updated to refer to a new object. This is the mistake I refer to. Assigning `j=i` causes the name `j` to refer to the object `i` refers to *at that point in time*. `j` is a name stored on the new lambda object and is not redefined to refer to anything else, so the named reference to the integer object remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

I find it surprising that nobody mentioned the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: I think that's more of a limitation in the current implementation, rather than a mistake in the design of the language itself.

Comment: @PiPeep - exactly. Jython has no GIL, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things I find most annoying in Python is using writelines() and readlines() on a file.  readlines() not only returns a list of lines, but it also still has the \n characters at the end of each line, so you have to always end up doing something like this to strip them:

```
lines = [l.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "") for l in f.readlines()]
```

And when you want to use writelines() to write lines to a file, you have to add \n at the end of every line in the list before you write them, sort of like this:

```
f.writelines([l + "\n" for l in lines])
```

writelines() and readlines() should take care of endline characters in an OS independent way, so you don't have to deal with it yourself.

You should just be able to go:

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

and it should return a list of lines, without \n or \r characters at the end of the lines.

Likewise, you should just be able to go:

```
f.writelines(lines)
```

To write a list of lines to a file, and it should use the operating systems preferred enline characters when writing the file, you shouldn't need to do this yourself to the list first.

Comment: `readlines()` is kind of deprecated for most purposes. Just use the file as an iterator. To chop off the ending newline, use line.rstrip('\r\n') which is also significantly more efficient than `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

My biggest dislike is `range()`, because it doesn't do what you'd expect, e.g.:

```
>>> for i in range(1,10): print i,
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

A naive user coming from another language would expect 10 to be printed as well.

Comment: It is at least consistent with Dijkstra's opinions :-) http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1950

Comment: Since this is non-obvious to a lot of people, but GvR and EWD agree, we may have an instance of "that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch." (from The Zen of Python/`import this`)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for liks; I have written a document on that topic some time ago: http://segfaulthunter.github.com/articles/biggestsurprise/

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of weird stuff in python in the way they handle builtins/constants. Like the following:

```
True = "hello"
False = "hello"
print True == False
```

That prints `True`...

```
def sorted(x):
  print "Haha, pwned"

sorted([4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Lolwut? `sorted` is a builtin global function. The worst example in practice is `list`, which people tend to use as a convenient name for a local variable and end up clobbering the global builtin.

Comment: While inconvenient, most dynamic languages allow you to shadow builtins.

Comment: Shadowing builtins, defun, let, cond, do, setf, the semicolon in let/where is very powerful in Lisp/Haskell.  However, in Python you have to explicitly keep an old version and remember to put it back although with also helps but its not as nice as let/where.